# A question about the word **would**

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I'm really hoping that someone can help me.

In these sentences what does **would** actually mean? Usually we can use would to talk about past habit, suggestions, advice, conditionals etc.

1.
He **would** get upset about that! (= I'm not surprised. Knowing him - this is a typical thing that he'd do)

or

2
A: She at all of biscuits and didn't leave any for anyone else.

B: Well, she **would**! (= I'm not surprised. Knowing her this is a typical thing that she'd do)

- What can I call this form of would if I'd like to read more about it? Why do we use 'would' here? How might it be described in a grammatical way?

Thanks!

Comment: These examples reflect the full OED definition 29 - *Was determined to; insisted on or persisted in ——ing. **Also (colloq.), could naturally or inevitably be expected to, esp. in the light of one's known character or tendencies.***

Comment: She would (do that) = she typically does that; it's something she is expected to do.

Comment: Ok, you're asking three questions instead of one, so minus points. I'll answer one. We use *would* there to express our feelings about someone else's behavior as something they do habitually., This can be neutral ("He would often park in that space.") or offended or indignant (your examples).